# Query multiple meta values

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, meta-value

I'm working on a 'checkbox filter' to query posts by checked values. See [this link](http://painini.nl/gap/?page_id=333) (*EDIT*: As you can see there are just 2 posts in this link, as soon as the user checks for 'MINI' it gets a good result, as soon as the user checks 'MINI' and 'COMPACT', it gives no results instead of the 2 posts). Now it works if the user only checks 1 value. As soon as the user the checks more then one it will give no results. I'm using following meta query code (it's part of a longer code, that's why there is the if statement):

```
if (gap_meta_values($key, $value)) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => $key,
                'value' => $value,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'

            );
```

So this works if there is only 1 meta value. However if there are more than one values it does not work. So I tried several things to get it work, I tought it was because there's no relation between the key and value. So I tried this:

```
if (gap_meta_values($key, $value)) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array (
                'key' => $key,
                'value' => $value,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )

        );
        }
```

But this neither seem to work. How to make this works so it will query all posts from the checked values? Thanks for your response.

Comment: i just check your ajax request `{metakey:'type',metavalue:'Mini',metakey:'type',metavalue:'Compact',metakey:'serie',metavalue:'600 series',method:'sortby',sort:'sortbytitle'}`.i think this willbe a array on php side in $_POST with same key like `metakey` and `metavalue`.how are you making diffrence between them ? can you just show code how are you handling data on phpside

Answer (score 1):

[You code is generating a broken `meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You code will produce something like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["relation"]=>
      string(2) "OR"
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(4) "test"
        ["value"]=>
        string(10) "test_value"
        ["compare"]=>
        string(4) "LIKE"
      }
    }
}
```

It should look like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["meta_query"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(2) "OR"
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["key"]=>
      string(4) "test"
      ["value"]=>
      string(10) "test_value"
      ["compare"]=>
      string(4) "LIKE"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is the trailing square brackets here: `$args['meta_query'][]` That is incorrect. To combine your values do something like this instead:

```
$meta_q = array();

$key ='test';
$value='test_value';

if (!empty($key) && !empty($value)) {
  $meta_q[] = array(
    'key' => $key,
    'value' => $value,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  );
}

$key2 ='test';
$value2='test_value';

if (!empty($key2) && !empty($value2)) {
  $meta_q[] = array(
    'key' => $key2,
    'value' => $value2,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  );
}

$args = array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  'meta_query' => $meta_q,
);
var_dump($args);
```